# Как правильно делать lazy load?

Tags: java, android, lazyloading

До этого времени все данные загружал просто когда человек открывает приложение в asynkTask. А теперь потребовалось воспользоваться кэшем и LazyLoad, только вот как правильно пользоваться я не могу понять. Нужно что б было к примеру как в вк, потянул список в низ и данные начинали обновляться -> если есть новые данные то загружаем, нет значит нет.

Вот такая структура мое проекта сейчас:

```
//сюда загружается json 
ArrayList<NewsObject> newsList; 
ListView list; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
//код 
                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); 
        newsList = new ArrayList<NewsObject>(); 
              //код  
              //загрузка новостей(новости все в json) 
              new NewsAsynkTask().execute(); 
} 

public class NewsAsynkTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, String> { 
                    //код 
                  protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 
                 //тут я добавляю json в обьект 
                 //потом добавляю в список, обьекты 
                   newsList.add(newsObject); 

} 
                  protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) { 
                  //включается адаптер  
                       NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.n_news_list_object, newsList); 
            list.setAdapter(adapter); 
} 
}
```

Какой алгоритм действий? Вот как я это представляю:

1. Открывается приложение, если есть интернет тогда считываем к примеру 10 постов последних постов.
2. Если пользователь потянул список вниз, обновляем данные, новые записи выводим.
3. Если пользователь добрался до конца списка, подгружаем еще 10 постов.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview?rq=1 Может поможет, там много ленивых загрузчиков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загрузка, если в конце списка! 
При первом запуске загрузит первую порцию.

```
 listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (!isLoading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= firstVisibleItem) {
                    isLoading = true; //После загрузки, опустить флаг 
                    load(); //Загрузка
                    footerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Отображение футера, прогресбар какой-нибудь внизу, после загрузки убрать.
                }
            }
        });
```